# Email when error occurs using NewRelic

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

I am using New Relic to monitor an application. I want New Relic to send an alert notification when an error(eg- 403,500 errors) occurs in the application.

I have followed [this](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts/alert-policies/examples/email-alert-notifications) documentation provided by NewRelic but it did not give me the desired results, I get notification only for the "unable to ping" alerts.

How am I supposed to make New Relic send me email notifications when an error occurs?

Answer (score 3):

New Relic doesn't currently support sending individual error alerts. You can set an alert on error rate (and set it quite low--0.001%, for example), which will then let you dig in to the Errors page to find the individual stack traces for exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you able to provide a link to where New Relic state that they don't currently support sending individual error alerts?

Comment: @Marklar I'm a New Relic customer can log in and see the feature simply isn't there.